# Exception: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, django

I am using model for keeping user info like profile picture and bio etc, but when i am signing up this error occurs.
Here is the code

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete='CASCADE')
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 500, default='', blank = True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 100, default='', blank = True)
    website = models.URLField(default='', blank = True)
    phone = models.IntegerField(default='', blank = True)
    image = models.FileField()

@receiver(post_save, sender = User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
        instance.userprofile.save()
```

Comment: remove `default='',` from this line `phone = models.IntegerField(default='', blank = True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

means that can not do `Type Conversion` on `''`.

I suppose `phone = models.IntegerField(default='', blank = True)` is the question.

Because you don't assign a value to `phone`, so it uses default value `''`, which can not be converted by `int()` in python.